# ruby on rails, creating new object, use create or new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, new-operator, createinstance

I am trying to create an object via an API, i.e. no forms are required, should I be doing `MyModel.new(:name => params[:name])` or `MyModel.create(:name => params[:name])` ?

Assume I have `resources : my_models` in `routes`

I checked and I see that methods can use the params hash ok.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`.new` makes an instance (but you'll still need to `.save` it).
while
`.create` makes an instance *and* saves it in one go.

Hopefully that helps your decision on which to use.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what are you want to get. `new` method simply instantiates new object and `create` method creates an object and saves it to the database, if validations pass.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, yes. I assume you are talking about ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-create.